# Select child input textbbox by parent class on focus in and focus out event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add "invalid-class" in my iti class div when someone focusin the input textbox and also remove the "invalid-class" class when someone focusout from the textbox. I want to do it by using .iti class. Is there any method in jquery for that

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <div class="d-flex position-relative">
        <div class="iti">
            <div class="iti__flag-container">
                <div class="iti__selected-flag" role="combobox">
                    <div class="iti__flag iti__in"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="form-control">
            <span class="error-block text-danger"><span>Invalid Phone Number</span></span>
        </div>
        <label for="phone" class="col-form-label ">Phone</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried below Code

```
$(".iti > input").focusin(function(){
    $(this).addClass("round");
});
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, i added it in my question

Comment: When you inspect the input via devtools, does the element have the class applied to it? What does your css look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus()` and `blur()`

I have added `active` so you can understand by red background on it.

You can add/remove your class accordingly.

```js
$('.iti input').focus( function() {
  if($(this).val()){
    $(this).parents('.iti').addClass('active round');
  }
    
});

$('.iti input').blur( function() {
    $(this).parents('.iti').removeClass('active round');
});

$('.iti input').on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val()){
      $(this).parents('.iti').addClass('active round');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('.iti').removeClass('active round');
    }
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iti">
        <div class="iti__flag-container">
            <div class="iti__selected-flag" role="combobox" aria-owns="iti-1__country-listbox" aria-expanded="false" title="India (भारत): +91">
                <div class="iti__flag iti__in"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Comment: There is one issue in above code, i want to add class on base of value, if phone number value  is blank then don't need to add any class. Right now problem is you select it by using input selector, so it gives me all the other form fields input value, i want only phone number text value.

Comment: you can use id `phone`

Comment: I want to use this code in another form also, in that form the phone number field id is different, so i want universal code for all the form.

Comment: check now and if not working then plz explain what you want ecept that working code.

Comment: I above fiddle it's working, but when i add your code in my file it's not working properly. I have 2 other divs before iti class div, is that the reason for not working?

Comment: @Amv then i need to know your other div classes name

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Devsi answer, however used toggle class instead of remove and add.

```js
$('input').on('focus blur', function() {
    $(this).parents('.iti').toggleClass('active round');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iti">
        <div class="iti__flag-container">
            <div class="iti__selected-flag" role="combobox" aria-owns="iti-1__country-listbox" aria-expanded="false" title="India (भारत): +91">
                <div class="iti__flag iti__in"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution in plain javascript.
If I understand correctly you have to add/remove a class for each input element in the outer div container. In this case you can use event delegation, in this way you must not add a listener for each element and you can add the listener to the container/root element. But there is a problem,  focus and blur events don't bubble thereby you have to use focusin and focusout.

```html
<div class="iti">
    <div class="iti__flag-container">
        <div class="iti__selected-flag" role="combobox" aria-owns="iti-1__country-listbox" aria-expanded="false" title="India (भारत): +91">
            <div class="iti__flag iti__in"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="form-control">
</div>

<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event)=>{
let inEl = document.querySelector(".iti"); 
inEl.addEventListener("focusin",handler);
inEl.addEventListener("focusout",handler);



});

function handler(event) {
  let target = event.target;

  switch(target.id){
    case "phone":
    case "anotherIdInput":
    target.classList.toggle("round");
    break;
 }
 }
</script>
```

The only problem is that you are forced to add a case for each input element in the switch (though this can be automatized too).
Furthermore I have not considered possible backward compatibility problems. For instance blur and focus are everywhere, focusin and focusout are DOM3, the same with addEventListener,and so on. It isn't safe to reference an element with the class because more elements can have the same class .